# Datatables responsive - column not collapsible to child row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10, responsiveness

I use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). Each row in all tables has it's own actions in a separate column (smtn like "edit item", "delete item" and so).

[image: actions column]

I use the [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension and it shrinks the table to width of a view and columns that do not fit that area are put into the "child row" (set of values visible on-demand under the plus button).

I would like to keep my actions column visible but on the right side of table. Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible

Datatables gives you the option to set priority to any column using columnDefs

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/priority

Default priority for columns is 10000. So you can assign a lower value for the action column so that its not hidden before others.